# Applying rowspan dynamically using angular JS ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I wanted to display the duplicate values in the rows to be clubbed into one and apply rowspan on that particular rows containing duplicate values. i am not sure whether i am clear in my question. take a look at the below table

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]:

I wanted that jason should be displayed once once and the rowspan should be two. in this particular example, and i should be able to apply it for further rows also if any duplications happen to be there.I saw a couple of similar questions in here but they do not fit to my requirement Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @Kenny i tried but it is giving weird results that is y i didnt post any code :( will you give me some idea how can i frame it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried a simple solution i dont know whether it is accurate and efficient or not using **ng-style**

```
<td ng-style="{ 'border-top' : {{x.NAME == consfeed[$index-1].NAME}} ? '1px solid white':'','border-bottom' : {{x.NAME == consfeed[$index+1].NAME}} ? '1px solid white':''}">{{ x.NAME == consfeed[$index-1].NAME ? "" : x.NAME }}</td>
```

which gave me the following result. Please correct me if i am wrong :|
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

posting the data sample

```
    [  
   {  
      "0":"5.0",
      "feedback":"5.0",
      "1":"5",
      "COUNT(fc.trainee_id)":"5",
      "2":"1",
      "sessions":"1",
      "3":"UET_Q4_18_EBK_FINFUNC_2017",
      "training_id":"UET_Q4_18_EBK_FINFUNC_2017",
      "4":"Giridhar Mohan Bhat",
      "NAME":"Giridhar Mohan Bhat",
      "5":null,
      "signoff_rating":null
   },
   {  
      "0":"4.4",
      "feedback":"4.4",
      "1":"5",
      "COUNT(fc.trainee_id)":"5",
      "2":"1",
      "sessions":"1",
      "3":"UET_Q3_10_HNB_FINTECH_2016",
      "training_id":"UET_Q3_10_HNB_FINTECH_2016",
      "4":"GGGGG",
      "NAME":"GGGGG",
      "5":null,
      "signoff_rating":null
   },
   {  
      "0":"4.7",
      "feedback":"4.7",
      "1":"10",
      "COUNT(fc.trainee_id)":"10",
      "2":"1",
      "sessions":"1",
      "3":"UET_Q3_5_SIB_FINTECH_2016",
      "training_id":"UET_Q3_5_SIB_FINTECH_2016",
      "4":"GGGG",
      "NAME":"GGGGG",
      "5":"7",
      "signoff_rating":"7"
   },
   {  
      "0":"3.9",
      "feedback":"3.9",
      "1":"10",
      "COUNT(fc.trainee_id)":"10",
      "2":"1",
      "sessions":"1",
      "3":"UET_Q3_5_SIB_FINTECH_2016",
      "training_id":"UET_Q3_5_SIB_FINTECH_2016",
      "4":"Abhishek",
      "NAME":"Abhishek",
      "5":"7",
      "signoff_rating":"7"
   },
   {  
      "0":"4.0",
      "feedback":"4.0",
      "1":"5",
      "COUNT(fc.trainee_id)":"5",
      "2":"1",
      "sessions":"1",
      "3":"UET_Q3_11_HNB_FINTECH_2016",
      "training_id":"UET_Q3_11_HNB_FINTECH_2016",
      "4":"Jason",
      "NAME":"Jason ",
      "5":null,
      "signoff_rating":null
   },
   {  
      "0":"4.8",
      "feedback":"4.8",
      "1":"20",
      "COUNT(fc.trainee_id)":"20",
      "2":"2",
      "sessions":"2",
      "3":"UET_Q3_5_SIB_FINTECH_2016",
      "training_id":"UET_Q3_5_SIB_FINTECH_2016",
      "4":"Jason",
      "NAME":"Jason ",
      "5":"7",
      "signoff_rating":"7"
   }
]
```

Comment: You may want to post another question involving your JSON data and how you are gathering the data from MySQL (or whatever database you are using) along with whatever server side setup you've got -- most JSON responses do not look like that. (I.e. the data isn't duplicated between named and non-named columns)

Comment: @Jhecht it solved my problem, the data same in non-named and named columns right ?

Answer (score 0):

Would this help? - https://plnkr.co/edit/vNq9l0ZcSzGWEipGeWId?p=preview

```
angular.module("SampleApp", [])
  .controller('SampleController',function() {

    var self = this;

    self.trainingDetails = [{
      trainer: 'Geetha',
      feedbacks: [4.4]
    }, {
      trainer: 'Jason',
      feedbacks: [4.0, 4.7]
    }];
  });

<body data-ng-controller="SampleController as ctrl">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Trainer</th>
      <th>Avg Feedback</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="training in ctrl.trainingDetails">
      <td rowspan={{training.feedbacks.length}}>{{::training.trainer}}</td>
      <td><div data-ng-repeat="feedback in training.feedbacks">{{::feedback}}</div></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</body>
```

Comment: but my json is not like the one you defined **trainer: 'Jason',
      feedbacks: [4.0, 4.7]** these are two individual rows coming database :|

Comment: you can always restructure your json at client side to render it as you wish. I would recommend restructuring the JSON rather than making the UI logic complex

Comment: i will try and let you know

Comment: @Jason can you update your question with what the data you get from the server looks like? would help us out too.

Comment: @Jhecht you want the Json that i got from the server ?